# How can i arrange array before specific array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I would like to arrange Array before found a specific array key. For example

Following is array.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array([package_name] => 10.4)
    [1] => Array([final_total] => 10.4)
    [2] => Array([package_name] => 10.5)
    [3] => Array([package_name] => 4.5)
    [4] => Array([final_total] => 15)
    [5] => Array([package_name] => 15.2)
    [6] => Array([final_total] => 15.2)
    [7] => Array([package_name] => 8.4)
    [8] => 8.4
)
```

And I want like array.

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [package_name] =>  array([0]=>10.4),
            [final_total] => 10.4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [package_name] => array(
                [0] => 10.5,
                [1] => 4.5   
            ),         
            [final_total] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [package_name] => array([0]=>15.2)            
            [final_total] => 15.2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [package_name] => array([0]=>8.4)            
            [final_total] => 8.4
        )

)
```

So What i want If  `final_total` key is found from array then set previous values(package_name) of `final_total` in a array.

Above example you can see there are 4 `final_total` key's of array so i want to set each package_name's value in a array that are previous value of final_total.

Following is my code.
This is my array

```
$main = array(array('package_name' => 10.4),array('final_total' => 10.4),array('package_name' => 10.5),array('package_name' => 4.5),array('final_total' => 15)
,array('package_name' => 15.2),array('final_total' => 15.2));
```

Code.

```
<?php 
$newArray = [];

$newPackag=[];
$previousValue='';
$currentKey=0;
$PreviousKey=0;
$i=0;
$main_keys = array_keys($main);

foreach ($main as $key => $value) {

     $curtent_item[] = isset($main[$key]['package_name']) ? $main[$key]['package_name'] : '';
        $currentKey = $key;
      if(@$main[$key]['final_total'] ==@$value['final_total']){         
            $previousValue = @$value['package_name'];
            $newArray[] = $previousValue;

            $myarray= array(@$main[$key]['package_name']);
            if (array_key_exists("final_total",$main[$key])){
                if($PreviousKey ==0){
                    $PreviousKey = $key+1;
                }else{
                    $PreviousKey = $key;
                }           
            }else{
                $keys = array_keys($main);
                $position = array_search($key, $keys);  

               echo "Curent Key =".$currentKey.'PreviousKey'.$PreviousKey.'</br>';
               if($currentKey != $PreviousKey){
              $nextKey = $keys[$currentKey+1 ];

               }            
            $newPackag1[]    = array('package_name'=>@$myarray);    
        }
        $mainArray = array('package'=>$newPackag1);

      }


            $i++;  

}
echo "<pre>NE page";print_r($newPackag1);
echo "<pre>";print_r($main);
```

anyone has better and correct solution. Above code which i am trying not able to get desire output.

Comment: Could you go back through your code and fix indentation and misspellings?  What is your question, what problems is your code having?  (And why are you dealing with such poorly structured data?)

Comment: While you are fiddling around with that code, this would be a perfect moment to learn test driven development. Sketch some simple cases, write test cases for them, implement the code, go to the more difficult cases. To help you further, one should at least know why there are two package names in the second array - what's the rule behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the snippet with modified data(surely will work for your case too),

```
$result = [];$i= 0;
foreach ($main as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $k = key($value);$v = array_shift($value);
        ($k != 'final_total' ? $result[$i][$k][] = $v : $result[$i][$k] = $v);
        if($k == 'final_total'){
            $i++;
        }
    } elseif (!empty($value)) {
        $result[$i]['final_total'] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1G1GC)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [package_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6.5
                    [1] => 9
                )

            [final_total] => 15.5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [package_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10.5
                )

            [final_total] => 10.5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [package_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 17.1
                )

            [final_total] => 17.1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [package_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9.8
                )

            [final_total] => 9.8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [package_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16
                )

            [final_total] => 16
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [package_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10.5
                )

            [final_total] => 10.5
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , It's work but i forgot to put original array in my question, I have put now that original in my question you can  see last array items[0] => 0.8 without key. when i tried with this output is different.

Comment: your array is unexpected when playing with two keys under consideration.

Comment: So how could we handle this scenario because i get this array only last value is come up without key. Is there anyway to set this last value with key final_total name ?

Comment: Always it will be without key or sometimes?

Comment: Always last value will be without key

Comment: Updated my snippet as per your requirement. Please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204525/discussion-between-rahul-and-david).

Comment: can you please come to chat

Comment: Great!! Thank you: